# Skip installation prompts during upgrade in terminal

Tags: command-line

Can I skip the questions asked during install in terminal?

I was writing `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo shutdown -h 1` so that the computer shuts down after updating. But I was wondering what if questions popup during updating like 256 MB updates `y/n`?

Answer (score 2):

Adding `-y` to `sudo apt-get upgrade` will make it assume *yes* to all queries.

[From the **man** page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man8/apt-get.8.html):

> ```
> -y, --yes, --assume-yes
>       Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and
>       run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as
>       changing a held package, trying to install a unauthenticated
>       package or removing an essential package occurs then apt-get will
>       abort. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.
> ```

So if you make your command look like this

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y && sudo shutdown -h 1
```

To run without risk of new password prompt before shutdown do this

```
sudo sh -c "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && shutdown -h 1"
```

it will run and "answer" *yes* to any prompts you have during `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

For more information on the command `apt-get` type in a terminal `man apt-get`.

Comment: What if there is a configuration screen without a y/n answer?

Comment: If it's a fault the command chain will break and the last `&&` will never be executed, the computer will not shutdown. I dont think there is a argument that ignores faults (that would also defect the purpose of the script since no updates would be installed on fault).

Comment: Depending on the time taken by `apt-get upgrade`, `sudo shutdown` may require the password to be entered again. If you want `shutdown` to run regardless of the exit status of the upgrade replace the last `&&` with `;`. `sudo sh -c "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && shutdown -h 1"` should help with the password problem of a long upgrade.